# Copy visible rows that matches criteria and multiply by percentage then paste to another sheet's last row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I can only successfully execute the above-mentioned subject if I am removing the criteria. But once I put it back it will not execute or do nothing. Below is my codes with criteria. I wonder how I will include the criteria and keep this code working. I need all the rows in column A that matches cell B2 in DB2 Sheet then copy to the last row of DB3 sheet. Appreciate any help.

```vb
Sub VisibleRowsAndMultiplyByPercentage()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowSource As Long, lastRowDest As Long
    Dim criteria As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Set source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB2")
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB3")
        
    ' Get the criteria value from cell B2 in destination sheet (Sheet5)
    criteria = wsSource.Range("B2").Value
      
    ' Find the last row in source sheet
    lastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find the last row in destination sheet column A
    lastRowDest = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    
    ' Loop through each row in column A of the source sheet
    For i = 3 To lastRowSource
        ' Check if the row is visible and column A matches the criteria (B2 value)
        If Not wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden And wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value = criteria Then
            ' Copy values from column 1 to 10
            For j = 1 To 10
                wsDestination.Cells(lastRowDest, 1).Resize(, 10).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 10).Value
            Next j
            ' Loop through columns 11 to 22 in the source row, multiply by percentage, and copy to destination sheet
            For j = 11 To 22
                ' Multiply the value by the corresponding percentage from row 1
                Dim multipliedValue As Double
                multipliedValue = wsSource.Cells(i, j).Value * wsSource.Cells(1, j).Value
                ' Copy the multiplied value to destination sheet
                wsDestination.Cells(lastRowDest, j).Value = multipliedValue
            Next j
            ' Move to the next row in destination sheet
            lastRowDest = lastRowDest + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `criteria` isn't declared, try it with it declared. Also, the first for-loop isn't necessary (you can assign the full 10 column-values at once) and you could create an array in the second one to paste all the values at once. Other than that, I can't immediately see anything that would cause an issue. If your rows are hidden due to a filter, you could also work with setting a range to the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to only have the non-hidden rows to loop through (idk how big your data set is).

Comment: Hi @Notus_Panda, would you mind to translate my codes based on your inputs please? I just have an issue with the criteria, other than that it's all good

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with translating. You don't have `Dim criteria As String`, this depends whether the value is a string or a number to compare and is likely what causes your code to do nothing as right now. As for the values, at once, something like this: `wsDestination.Cells(lastRowDest, 1).Resize(,10).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Resize(,10).Value`

Comment: @Notus_Panda I updated the codes above based on your inputs and got Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. I also just try declaring the criteria without the resize code and it still do nothing.

Comment: I meant for that line to replace the `for j = 1 To 10` loop, should've been more clear, sorry.

Comment: @Notus_Panda sorry for being a noob as well. I updated again the codes above but still doing nothing when I run the codes.

Comment: Your code works just fine in my test-wb but I used just a string as Criteria. Are your A-values numbers as text and your B2 just a number perhaps? That's the only explanation for your code not doing anything for as far as I can see..

Comment: sorry is FY24, FY25 etc.. considered a String? I also used tried String and it is not doing anything as well

Comment: Yes, those would be strings. Then there shouldn't be any issue with your code as I said, it works for me. Can you try stepping through your code with F8 to see if you even get in your If-clause for a row you'd expect it to work?

Comment: @Notus_Panda confirmed it is now working. Thanks a lot for all your help. Let me know how I will commend you on this.

Comment: Posted an answer with the edits I would do as previously mentioned. I saw you had put the line in the for j = 1 to 10 loop instead of replacing it altogether so I fixed that too :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your code adjusted to what I mentioned in the comments:

```
Sub VisibleRowsAndMultiplyByPercentage()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowSource As Long, lastRowDest As Long
    Dim criteria As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Set source and destination worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB2")
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB3")
        
    ' Get the criteria value from cell B2 in destination sheet (Sheet5)
    criteria = wsSource.Range("B2").Value
      
    ' Find the last row in source sheet
    lastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find the last row in destination sheet column A
    lastRowDest = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim arrPrint
    Dim multipliedValue As Double
    ReDim arrPrint(1 To 12)
    ' Loop through each row in column A of the source sheet
    For i = 3 To lastRowSource
        ' Check if the row is visible and column A matches the criteria (B2 value)
        If Not wsSource.Rows(i).Hidden And wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value = criteria Then
            ' Copy values from column 1 to 10
            wsDestination.Cells(lastRowDest, 1).Resize(, 10).Value = wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 10).Value
            ' Loop through columns 11 to 22 in the source row, multiply by percentage, and copy to destination sheet
            For j = 11 To 22
                ' Multiply the value by the corresponding percentage from row 1
                arrPrint(j - 10) = wsSource.Cells(i, j).Value * wsSource.Cells(1, j).Value
            Next j
            ' Copy the multiplied value to destination sheet
            wsDestination.Cells(lastRowDest, 11).Resize(, UBound(arrPrint)).Value = arrPrint
            ' Move to the next row in destination sheet
            lastRowDest = lastRowDest + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Use `Option Explicit` to prevent undeclared variables (and other such issues) causing issues; see [this](https://excelchamps.com/vba/option-explicit/) how to set it in all your future code automatically.